# Using Do While in C [Find Mistake]

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I have a relatively simple program that asks for user input between a range and then checks it using Do - while loop.

```
int n;
do
{ 
 print ("hello, world\n");
 n = getvalue() //just making this syntax up.It takes value from user
}
while (n<0 && n>99);
print ("%d\n",n);
```

I want to prompt the user to input another value if he/she enters either a negative number or a triple digit number (or higher). But the condition within while is not being validated.

**What the output looks like:**

No matter what number I enter, it get printed. i.e. -2 is printed as -2, 101 as 101 and 50 as 50. Ideally, -2 should prompt user to enter a number again, so should 101 and only 50 should print out.

Comment: You realize that's an infinite loop, right?

Comment: Where do you assign a value to n ?

Comment: Post more details of code...

Comment: What value are you entering for which the test fails? And what do you mean "does not work"? Please give a specific number and what you expect the loop to do - continue or end?

Comment: Too many syntax errors this won't even run

Comment: `(n<0 && n>99)` which number is smaller than 0 and larger then 99?

Comment: @Wimmel - Thanks. That was the mistake. It should have been || instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your rather cryptic condition of `n < 0 && n > 99`, which can't reasonably be satisfied.

You need to look more closely at the logic of your loop. If you want to prompt the user again if they enter a number less than zero *or* greater than 99, you need to use the logical *or* operator `||`.

```
while (n < 0 || n > 99);
```